# vagrant box not found blank error

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, windows-10, box

I am trying to use the `ubuntu/trusty64` box in vagrant on my windows 10 machine. I originally was using `ubuntu/precise64` in my vagrant file and that works fine. I tried only changing the line `config.vm.box = "ubuntu/precise64"` to now use the trusty64, but when I used the command `vagrant up` it gave me the output:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
default: Box Provider: virtualbox
default: Box Version: >= 0

The box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
'vagrant login'. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:
URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64"]
Error:
```

with a blank error. I tried logging in, my command prompt is in administrative mode, and I tried just grabbing the `ubuntu/trusty64` box by itself with `vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64` (that command gave me no error), then `vagrant up` but got the same output.

Comment: can you access `https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64` from your browser ? do you need to set a proxy to access internet ?

Comment: I don't believe I need a proxy. I can access that link from my browser.

Comment: download from command line `wget https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20160601.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just missing Microsoft Visual c++ Redistributable x86

downloadable here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328

I found the answer on github at:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6754